# jQuery Drag and Drop on Polygon Shapes using css clip-path

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, clip-path

I am developing an application but i am facing issue when implementing jQuery Drag and Drop. Please have a look at [Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZdzVo).

What I am developing is Polygon shapes using css Clip Path. When i drag Swipe Me Circle and drop on Red it return alert for "Dropped on Red" but it also return alert for "Dropped on Blue" Whereas, Circle is Dropped on Red.

I will be Thankful for your Help.

My jQuery Code is :

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#RedTriangle" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        alert("Dropped On Red");
      }
    });
    $( "#GreenTriangle" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        alert("Dropped On Green");
      }
    });
    $( "#BlueTriangle" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        alert("Dropped On Blue");
      }
    });                
  });
```

Comment: Reason why you get two alerts is that all the div's are rectangular in shape, even though you view them as triangle. Therefore the div's overlap at some areas and when dropping in those area event gets trigged for both the div's.

Comment: same issue using svg

Comment: As was suggested, the `div`elements are boxes, and using CSS they are being clipped, but the bounding is a box. So to accomplish this, you will need to look at the Mouse `x` & `y` values. You'd have to calculate the triangle area and determine if the mouse is inside this area when the item is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

I do an other JsFiddle for you. With svg.

And i use :

```
<svg width='100%' height='50%' viewBox="0 0 120 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon class="right" points="51 37, 100 100, 100 1"/>
  <polygon class="left" points="0 1,0 100,49 37"/>
  <polygon class="bottom" points="50 37, 1 100, 99 100"/>
</svg>
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/32T2a/313/

Comment: thanks for your effort. if you leave swipe me button on Red area, it return message hover blue. whereas it suppose to return alert for hover read.

Comment: and if you use jquery drag and drop, you will get drop event invoked twice. which is also same behavior using svg which i am facing using div

Comment: So, we must delete  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); for your cursor. 

I have find this solution ! :) http://jsfiddle.net/32T2a/314/

Comment: great. what was issue due to transform  translate? do you think it will work also fine with jquery droppable instead of mouseup event? my requirment is to implement jquery draggable and droppable not mouse events

Comment: because if you click on circle without moving it will return alert for all pages and will invoke alert of you click on right side of circle for green, when click on half left it will alert for red and when click on below half bottom it will alert for blue.

Comment: the transform translate move our cursor when we wouild drag the element. Its just that. 

We can't add event droppable on element polygon :(

Comment: also without moving dragger, you click on any location it will return alert.

Comment: nope. mouse end fires if it is between any two polygon and on first half if you click it will alert red clicked and if on bottom half you click it will return bottom click. click on dragger invoke alert

Comment: nope do not work. place swipe me anywhere and then click mouse whereas i dnt want mouse to be click or events invoke on click, what i need is invoke only on drop

Comment: sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Greg if you click mouse on swipe me button it alert whereas i want it after drag from one location to other

Comment: On Chrome and with this JsFiddle. I haven't same thing I think : http://jsfiddle.net/32T2a/318/

Comment: please do not click in center of swipe me button

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 div on each other.
You must use svg in HTML, and create your element in SVG.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...>
      //content
    </svg>
```

For exemple, see here https://jsfiddle.net/EXqPa/31/

Hope that helps

Comment: please use jquery drag and drop. my issue is using drag and drop. on click or mouse enter it works fine for both div clip path and svg but drag and drop using jquery invoke events for all intersecting elements. please check my code.

Comment: I check your code. 
You have many DIV on each other, so you can't to know what div is hover. 
You must use svg html for to know element is hover